# how to create toast in java to show value of a computation

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a calculator that shows the result using a toast.

my code is

```
Button addBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.additionBtn);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
        EditText inputFirst = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.inputTextFirst);
        String message= inputFirst.getText().toString();

        EditText inputSecond = (EditText)findViewById     (R.id.inputTextSecond);
        String message2= inputSecond.getText().toString();





            int first = Integer.parseInt(message);
            int second = Integer.parseInt(message2);

            int sum = first + second;
            TextView resTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewResult);
            resTxt.setText("Result is  " +sum);


 Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView ResTxt=(TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.viewResult);
            resTxt.setText("answer is" + sum);


        }       });

}
```

it manages to show the result in a label. but with the toast, it is giving me notification that makeText not applicable to arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this ,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`makeText` takes as first parameter a Context object, but this, in your case, refers to the object of the inner anonymous class `new View.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

if it inside your activity then you should write this:

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this ,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

if it's outside your class, you'll need to get your activity context